# Repopulate radio buttons on failed validation (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with CodeIgniter repopulating a form after validation fails.

**HTML:**

```
<label for="public">Anyone</label>
<input type="radio" name="target" value="public" <?php echo set_radio('target', 'public', TRUE); ?> />

<label for="direct">Specific</label>
<input type="radio" name="target" value="direct" <?php echo set_radio('target', 'direct'); ?> />
```

When I first load the form I get this source code:

```
<label for="public">Anyone</label>
<input type="radio" name="target" value="public"  checked="checked" />

<label for="direct">Specific</label>
<input type="radio" name="target" value="direct"  />
```

... so the third parameter is working (the default "TRUE")

But when I submit the form with validation errors on other fields, the form is reloaded with no radio button selected.

A `var_dump($_POST)` after submitting (with intentional validation errors on other fields) shows this:

```
array (size=9)
  'target' => string 'direct' (length=6)
   ...
```

but no radio button is selected.

Got to be something simple... help?

Comment: But that's how radio buttons work...? As per the codeIgniter Manual.... no? See here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html right at the bottom.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/16473459/3574819

Comment: @FuzzyTree - thank you. That did the trick. (You need to add a fake rule).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is apparently to add a fake rule to the radio button.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules("tenderType", "", "trim");
```

Thanks to @FuzzyTree pointing to the solution here: stackoverflow.com/q/16473459/3574819